# Showing month names in English when using UIDatePicker when device region format is arabic

Tags: iphone

How to Show month names in English when using UIDatePicker when device region format is arabic.
Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using `localeWithLocaleIdentifier:` by passing current locale to UIDatePicker [refer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSLocale/localeWithLocaleIdentifier%3a)